# How to assign a serial number to every element of a class in HTML?

Tags: jquery, dom, analytics

I need to assign a serial number (1, 2, 3, ...) to every HTML element of a given class, regardless of where it occurs in the DOM hierarchy, and more specifically, I need every element to be able to ask itself - *"what is my serial number"*?

This strange requirement comes from the world of Web Analytics and trying to report on what exactly end-users are doing on the site.

*Regardless of where it occurs in the hierarchy* means I cannot use jQuery's `.prevAll()` - that would only work if all elements of the same class are siblings.

Example

```
<div class="x">I am div #1</div>
<div class="other">
  <div class="x">I am div #2</div>
  <div class="x">I am div #3</div>
</div>
<div class="x">I am div #4</div>
```

Two elements of the relevant class `x` will never be nested.

Comment: *"What is my serial number?"* is very vague... Please be more specific. Is this data programmatically extracted from said element? Is this something another application needs to access or is this for the user? What form does the SN finally become? A string? A number? a mix of both? Does this serial number require a certain pattern? Max chars? Min chars? Must begin with a letter? Begin with 2 or more letters? Did you really just want a simple `1, 2, 3...`?

Comment: Really it's a simple 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: http://pagedemos.com/reeeebkw5rcm/ Hover over the squares for serial numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you mean under the "serial-number".

```
$(".x").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).data("serial-number", index+1); // if you need hidden data
    $(this).attr("data-serial-number", index+1); // if you need attribute data
    $(this).text("I am div #" + (index+1)); // if you need to show it
});
```

then you can get this data back

```
console.log($(".x").eq(1).data("serial-number"));
```